# How can we hear Tyrion pee when he urinates off the top of the Wall?

Tags: game-of-thrones

How can we hear Tyrion's pee when he is pissing off of the Wall?

It is way, way down and there is no way we could hear this. What is the explanation?

Comment: Am I wrong?????

Comment: No, you're not wrong. Also, that little bastard first pissed, then shook the other bastard's hand.

Comment: @SQB, buuuuut, this kind of question not for this site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Someone goofed

This answer comes from an out of universe perspective and is mainly an educated guess but it is likely that someone goofed. The "wee noise" starts the second Tyrion started weeing which means it is just a generic stock wee noise. It also starts before Tyrion is in shot so it gives the viewer a better experience to know what he is doing. In real life there likely would be no noise but this gives an odd experience for the viewer especially with how it is filmed.

Comment: FWIW I thoroughly regret analysing this video.

Comment: LOL, That is good enough for me. +1